# Jquery .stop is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im having magicline.stop is not a function error while im trying to create a underline sliding effect to navbar. I tried to figure it out but i couldnt. Here my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-0 fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container" id="mainBar">
          <a href="#section1" class="navbar-brand">
            <!-- Logo Image -->
            <img id="mainLogo" src="" width="200" alt=""
              class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2">
          </a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navMenuItems">
              <li class="nav-item one"><a href="#section2" class="nav-link">M</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ml-2 two"><a href="#section3" class="nav-link">Ü</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ml-2 three"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">İ</a></li>
              <hr class="navmenuLine"/>
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle language" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                TR
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">EN</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

My JS

```
$(function() {

  var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
      $mainNav = $(".navMenuItems");

  $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
  var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

  $magicLine
      .width($(".one").width())
      .css("left", $(".one a").position().left)
      .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
      .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

  $(".navMenuItems li a").hover(function() {
      $el = $(this);
      leftPos = $el.position().left;
      newWidth = $el.parent().width();
      $magicLine.stop().animate({
          left: leftPos,
          width: newWidth
      });
  }, function() {
      $magicLine.stop().animate({
          left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
          width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
      });    
  });
});
```

There are 2 stop functions here and both of them giving me errors. Thanks for helps.

Comment: Are you using some kind of slim/custom version of jQuery?

Comment: Yes im using slim version. is this the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Ok thats the problem :D Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the variable `$magicLine` is not undefined.

If it is still not working please share the errors with us.

Comment: Its okay it was causing because of the slim version of jquery. I import min version and problem solved. Thank you

Comment: Great news! enjoy coding.